# Using React with Lerna

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, lerna

I am trying to build a proof-of-concept using Lerna and React.

Here's the repository:

https://github.com/SeanPlusPlus/lerna-react

So far, the above works if you run this:

```
git clone git@github.com:SeanPlusPlus/lerna-react.git
cd lerna-react
lerna bootstrap
cd packages/app
yarn start
```

In `packages/app/src/App.js` I am importing and rendering the `Headline` component (note, I used `create-react-app` to create this directory):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Headline from 'headline';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        { Headline }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The `Headline` component in `packages/headline/index.jsx` is using the `React.createElement` function:

```
import React from 'react';

// const Headline = () => (
//   <h1>Hello Lerna + React</h1>
// )

const Headline = React.createElement('div', null,
  React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello Lerna')
)

export default Headline
```

And, as you can see, the function returning JSX is commented out.

... Now ... If I update this file to return JSX instead:

```
import React from 'react';

const Headline = () => (
  <h1>Hello Lerna + React</h1>
)

export default Headline
```

My app returns this error:

```
Failed to compile.

../headline/index.jsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| const Headline = () => (
|   <h1>Hello Lerna + React</h1>
| )
```

How do I export JSX from my `Headline` component?

Comment: Could it be that the compiler assumes you're trying to return React in your headline method? (Hello Lerna + React) Perhaps try a different message.

Comment: Yup, I think so. Had to compile it and then import the compiled code. thx!

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

https://github.com/SeanPlusPlus/lerna-react/tree/react-babel

I needed to install babel and compile my `headline` component.

Comment: I am also stuck in the same situation. based on your answer, is it really necessary to build the package components every time? can't we have them as es6 modules and let webpack resolve and transpile them? because I don't want to run my babel start every time I change something in package components. it will make development slow. unless I use watch which I think unnecessary

Comment: also what about components that have scss imported ?

Comment: --watch will automatically build it