# Importing JavaScript to TypeScript app with Lerna

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lerna

I try to create a monorepo with 2 React packages:

- TypeScript (npx create-react-app `app` --template typescript)
- JavaScript (`ui`)

I've got a basic `lerna.json` configuration

```
{
  "packages": ["packages/*"],
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

In the `ui` package I simply export one Button (from `src/Button.jsx`):

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = () => {
  return (
    <button>
      Start
    </button>
  )
}

export default Button;
```

I've bootstrapped `app` to use the `ui` package.
Importing it inside the `app` causes the following error:

```
Failed to compile
/lerna-demo/packages/ui/src/Button.jsx 5:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| const Button = () => {
|   return (
>     <button>
|       Start
|     </button>
```

Is there a way to add a loader to lerna or `app` to fix the import?

EDIT

The project structure:

```
lerna-demo/
  - node_modules/
  - lerna.json
  - package.json
  - packages/
    - app (created using create-react-app)
      - ...
    - ui
      - node_modules/
      - package.json
      - yarn.lock
      - src/
        - Button.jsx
```

The way I import the Button component:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import * as Button from 'ui/src/Button';

const App: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: write more code - the import and the error

Comment: @Adidi I've update the question

Comment: @Bartek I'd check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179670/using-react-with-lerna

Comment: @NelsonYeung it worked :) I additionally had to add `"noImplicitAny": false` to tsconfig.json

Answer (score 2):

In your `tsconfig.json` created by CRA you will need to tell the compiler to include also the ui pacakge so in your example its something like that:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src", "../ui/src",
  ]
}
```

Another option is to extend your base lerna `tsconfig.json` and there its already points to your package with `path` I guess - so from your CRA `tsconfig.json` just add this:

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
```

and in base `tsconfig.json` u should define the alias name to the path:
main `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "ui/*": ["./packages/ui/*"],
```

Comment: I have the exact same case than in the question.  
Adding `paths` in base tsconfig or include in the package tslint does not work.  
I could only see the error message changes sometimes.  
It seems that developers of CRA don't want you to be able to do this.
An error message will appear: `The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)
`
I think people have faced the same issue and looking for work-arounds.
I haven't found the magic tweak so far but will come back.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66426351/868724) and was able to import my separate standalone package in my lerna monorepo into my CRA typescript app by using [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) and pointing the webpack config to my standalone package. I find this solution easier to manage instead of ejecting from your existing CRA config.

Given this structure:

```
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── app
│   ├── ui
└── yarn.lock
```

...here are the main steps:

1. **Install `craco` in `app/package.json`**:

```sh
yarn add @craco/craco
```

2. **Create a `craco.config.js` file in the CRA project root**

```
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── craco.config.json <--- in CRA project root
│   │  
│   ├── ui
│   │   ├── src
│   
│   
└── yarn.lock
```

3. **Point the webpack config to the shared module**

```js
// project/app/craco.config.js
// ---
const path = require('path');
/**
 * ALlows us to edit create-react-app configuration
 * without ejecting.
 *
 *
 */
const { getLoader, loaderByName } = require('@craco/craco');
// Replace `components` with your folder's structure.
// Again, Here I'm showcasing my current project.
const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, '../ui');
/**
 * This is extremely important if you're using a CI/CD to build and deploy 
 * your code!!! Read!
 * 
 * If you create a package with a namespace, such as name is @schon/components, you need
 * to add what I've commented down below. Otherwise Yarn will fail in CI/CD environments!!
 */
// const uiComponents = path.join(
//   __dirname,
//   './node_modules/ui',
// );

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
      // https://medium.com/frontend-digest/using-create-react-app-in-a-monorepo-a4e6f25be7aa
      const { isFound, match } = getLoader(
        webpackConfig,
        loaderByName('babel-loader'),
      );
      if (isFound) {
        const include = Array.isArray(match.loader.include)
          ? match.loader.include
          : [match.loader.include];
        // match.loader.include = include.concat(absolutePath, uiComponents);
        match.loader.include = include.concat(absolutePath);
      }
      return {
        ...webpackConfig,
        /**
         * Optionally, other webpack configuration details.
         */
        // optimization: {
        //   splitChunks: {
        //   },
        // },
      };
    },
  },
  
};
```